# Facebook tag fb:google-analytics vs adding the Google analytics JavaScript mysel

Tags: facebook, google-analytics

when why and where to use each one of those method? 
what are the advantages and disadvantages of each method ?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In FBML canvas applications facebook doesn't allow using regular javascript, instead they provide JS wrapper called [FBJS](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBJS) with limited functionality and different syntax. Adding google analytics on such FBML pages would be impossible as it relies on pure javascript, so for such apps `fb:google-analytics` was introduced.

Comment: so if i can insert JavaScript in my app 
no real advantage in using fb:google-analytics tag ???